# Gap between the two frequencies in FSK

Tags: electrical-engineering, rf-electronics

Frequency shift keying uses at least two different frequencies. How much should be the difference between the two frequencies so that the receiver reads the signal properly reliably? Is there any theoretical law or empirical norm?

Comment: It is related to the baud rate.  The faster you want to distinguish between two frequencies, the further apart they need to be.  Put another way, it takes longer to distinguish between two frequencies to the same signal to noise ratio if the frequency change is slight.

Comment: Given the 10 or 15 types of FSK listed at Wikipedia, you may need to reduce the scope of this question.

Comment: there is a stackexchange for ham radio questions- try posting your question there.